# How to trasnform date to formatted string in a Odoo module?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

have a Date field that is filled in with the current date. On the other hand, I have a calculated field that I need to be this date that has been generated, but with the format yyyymmddhhmmss using the autogenerated field. There is de class:

```
class incidencia(models.Model):
    _name = 'incidencias.incidencia'

    fecha_inicio = fields.Date(default=fields.Date.today, required=True)
    name = fields.Char(compute='_asignar_nombre', required=True)

    @api.depends('fecha_inicio')
    def _asignar_nombre(self):
        #¿?
```

Any ideas? I just started with Odoo and I'm not sure how to deal with the data types.

Comment: If you want date and time both then use Datetime field insted of Date field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class incidencia(models.Model):
    _name = 'incidencias.incidencia'

    fecha_inicio = fields.Date(default=fields.Date.today, required=True)
    name = fields.Char(compute='_asignar_nombre', required=True)

    @api.depends('fecha_inicio')
    def _asignar_nombre(self):
        for record in self:
            record.name = fields.Date.from_string(
                record.fecha_inicio).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

*Note*: as you have chosen [`Date`](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Date) instead of [`Datetime`](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Datetime), you will get zeros for hours, minutes and seconds in the formatted name, as time information is not stored in a [`Date`](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Date) field. If you need to keep track of time as well, I would suggest to use [`Datetime`](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Datetime). Note to change to [`odoo.fields.Datetime.from_string`](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Datetime.from_string) in the compute function if you decide to use [`Datetime`](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Datetime).